# Removing points from an algebraic variety

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $I$ be an ideal in a (let's say commutative) ring $R$.  Now for some $x \in R$, define $I_x = \{ r \in R | r x \in I \}$.  Then one can see $I_x$ is an ideal containing $I$.  If we consider the quotient $R / I$, then $I_x / I$ is the annihilator of the class of $x$ in $R / I$.

Now consider the case where $R$ is a polynomial ring over some field.  Then we can consider the algebraic variety defined by the vanishing locus, $V(I)$, of $I$, and then $V(I_p)$ is a subset of $V(I)$.  Then it seems like $V(I_p)$ is closely related to the set of points that vanish on $I$ but do not vanish on $p$.  Namely, if $x$ is in $V(I) \setminus V(I_p)$, then there must exist some $q$ in $I_p$ with $q(x) \neq 0$, but then since $q p$ is in $I$, $q(x) p(x) = 0$ and so $x$ is a root of $p$.  I'm not sure if all such roots of $p$ get removed, and perhaps it's not true, or requires stronger conditions.

Is there a simpler way to state some of the above, and some existing theory to describe this?  I'm particularly interested in the case where $p$ is the Vandermonde polynomial and this construction removes roots where some of the variables coincide.

Comment: If $I$ is the set of polynomials $\in R=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ vanishing on the whole of $A\subset \overline{k}^n$ and $f\in R$ then yes $\{ r\in R, rf \in I\}$ is the set of polynomials vanishing on the whole of $A-\{ a\in A, f(a)=0\}$.

Comment: In an arbitrary ring it works the same way if you assume that $I$ is the intersection of a set of prime ideals $P_i$ (so $rf\in \bigcap P_i$ iff $r\in \bigcap_{f\not \in P_i} P_i$).

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things.  So it is generally true that the ideal in question is the vanishing ideal of the set with those points removed, but I guess the issue is that this may not be an algebraic set, and so the vanishing locus of that ideal may be strictly larger.  Then it will be true that any points removed in that vanishing locus must have f(a) = 0, as I had argued, but not all such points will be removed.  A simple example is when A is all of k^n, in which case I = {0} and I_p will also be zero for any p, so that V(I_p) in fact is the same as V(I) and no points are removed.

Comment: A couple extra comments - this can be naturally extended from the zeros of a polynomial to the zeros of an ideal $J$ - just define $I_J = \{ r \in R | r j \in I, \forall j \in J \}$.  Another seemingly related construction is to add a new variable, $t$, to the polynomial ring and consider the ideal generated by the original ideal $I$ and the polynomial $t p - 1$ - this has a unique zero for every point in A for which $p$ is non-zero.  Are these constructions related, and do they have a name?  Is this maybe related to localization of a ring?